# replace url in Django template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

---

```
{% if shelf.script or shelf.log_url %}
{% if shelf.log_url %}
    Log URL: {{ shelf.log_url }}<br />
{% endif %}
{% if shelf.log_url %}
    <b>Another URL:</b> {{ shelf.log_url.replace("/tmp/BOOTLOG/", "http://www.sxp.com") }}<br />
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I have already got a log URL, I would like to update this URL with a domain address and adding /index.html to at the end.

I would like to replace this URL

***shelf.log_url output = /tmp/BOOTLOG/darwin_12345.tgz***

to something like this.

***www.sxp.com/darwin_12345/index.html***

***How can I do in Django template ?***

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the template? Why not in the view, or by defining a method on whatever `shelf` is?

Comment: clearly, logic in views. The most possible

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by a custom template tag. You can find more about custom template tags at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

you should try using custom filter for this. and you will get better idea from [Django custom filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

for example

```
{{shelf.log_url|replace:"url you need"}}
```

add filter in your any file for example filters.py

```
@register.filter(name='replace')
def replace(url, new_url):
    line = url.replace('/tmp/BOOTLOG/', new_url)
    return line
```